# Pop up on listing screen using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working on mobile app.I want pop-up to appear on click of icon(carat-r). Actually i'm not gettin where to link. Below is my code. Thanks in advance

```
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h1>weekdays</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-inset="true">
    <li ><a href="#">
    <h2>Sunday</h2>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
    <h2>monday</h2>
    </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about clicking the Sunday and Monday links to launch the popup like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9dovj480/

Comment: @ezanker , thank you for your valuable reply. I want popup to launch only on click of icon not on sunday and monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to launch a popup when the icon is clicked, but still have the rest of the listitem be a regular link, you should use the split button option on the listview:

**http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/listview/#Splitbuttons**

You can set the icon to carat-r using the `data-split-icon` attribute.

In your markup:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="carat-r">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><h2>Sunday</h2></a>
        <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9dovj480/1/)**

Comment: Is it possible to link to Carat-r icon without "data-split-icon" in  normal case. (Dont want popup to launch). The link should go to next page

Comment: @neeraj, so you want some listitems that simply navigate no matter where you click, and others that launch a popup on the arrow, but navigate when you click elsewhere? The icon itself is in the ::after pseudo element, so cannot respond to click itself.

Comment: @neeraj, you can leave out the second anchor tag on items that don't need the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9dovj480/2/ In this demo, sunday has popup, monday does not.

Comment: @ ezanker , thank you for your valuable reply. In demo,(second anchor tag) if i click on icon (if i link) it should go to next page. Is it possible ?

Comment: @neeraj, yes, just set the href of the anchor tag to the next page.

Comment: if I link  <div id="tabs">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-inset="true" >
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">
    <h2>monday</h2>
    </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> if I link ,the anchor is setting for whole list , I want it to be enabled only on click of icon